# How to programmatically list member entities of an Organic Group?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

How can I programmatically get a list of member entities of an Organic Group?

(I know how to get a list of group members using Views — I'd prefer to do this using the Organic Groups API, but haven't been able to find the right method.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or via DBTNG:

```
$query = db_select("og_membership", "ogm");
$query->condition("ogm.gid", $yourGroupID, "=");
$query->condition("ogm.group_type", "node", "=");
$query->fields("ogm", array("entity_type", "etid"));
$result = $query->execute();
print_r($result->fetchAll());
```

...which allows you to join other tables, rather than having to filter the result set in PHP code as you would if using `EntityFieldQuery`.

Answer (score 14):

Using directly the Organic Groups API:

```
og_get_group_members_properties($yourGroupNode, array(), 'members', 'node');
```

gives you an array of user ids.

To obtain only active, pending or blocked users, you can put 'members__1', 'members__2' or 'members__3' in place of 'members', like in this example:

```
og_get_group_members_properties($yourGroupNode, array(), 'members__1', 'node');
```

of, if you prefer, like this one:

```
og_get_group_members_properties($yourGroupNode, array(), 'members__' . OG_STATE_ACTIVE, 'node');
```

Example of the returned value:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 48
    [1] => 49
    [2] => 51
)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 8):

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query
  ->entityCondition("entity_type", "og_membership", "=")
  ->propertyCondition("gid", $yourGroupID, "=");
$result = $query->execute();
print_r($result["og_membership"]);
```

(Based on http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_load/7#comment-14544)

Answer (score 2):

smokris solution worked but I found another way with `EntityFieldQuery`:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->fieldCondition('og_group_ref', 'target_id', $yourGroupID)
  ->execute();
```

Example of the returned value:

```
{"node":
  {"22":{"nid":"22","vid":"22","type":"panoramique"},
   "32":{"nid":"32","vid":"32","type":"panoramique"},
   "35":{"nid":"35","vid":"35","type":"panoramique"},
   "36":{"nid":"36","vid":"36","type":"panoramique"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending answer from [@smokris](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/104/smokris).

The active status for the  memberships is "1"  (`->condition('ogm.state', 1, '=')` ).

```
function _get_users_in_group($gid) {
  $query = db_select('users', 'u');

  $query
    ->condition('u.uid', 0, '<>')
    ->condition('u.status', 1, '=')
    ->condition('ogm.state', 1, '=')
    ->fields('u', array('uid', 'name'))
    ->join('og_membership', 'ogm', "ogm.gid = :gid AND u.uid = ogm.etid AND ogm.entity_type = 'user'", array(':gid' => $gid));
  return $query->execute();
}
```